# how to calculate how many days there are from today to the next working day?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a working day table  for example today is The 10.02.2023

| oper_day | is_oper_day |
| --- | --- |
| 09.02.2023 | 1 |
| 10.02.2023 | 1 |
| 11.02.2023 | 0 |
| 12.02.2023 | 0 |
| 13.02.2023 | 1 |
| 14.02.2023 | 1 |

I want to calculate  count day from today to the next working day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the number of days from today to the next working day then, assuming `is_oper_day` represents a boolean and `1` means it is a working day, you can use:

```sql
SELECT MIN(oper_day) - TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS num_working_days
FROM   table_name
WHERE  oper_day > TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    is_oper_day = 1;
```

If you want the number of days from a specific day (i.e. `2023-02-10`) then replace `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` with the specific date:

```sql
SELECT MIN(oper_day) - DATE '2023-02-10' AS num_working_days
FROM   table_name
WHERE  oper_day > DATE '2023-02-10'
AND    is_oper_day = 1;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c3f8/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
select min(oper_day)-&v_ref_date
from oper_calendar
where oper_day>&v_ref_date
```

Comment: This will count the number of days to the next row in the table irrespective of what the `is_oper_day` value is for the next row.